# Search all favorite tags at once

Tags: support, tag-search

I'm constantly seeing myself having to go through a long process to get my search result for unanswered questions and I can't seem to find the efficient way to go about it.

I have saved favorite tags [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax), and [php](/questions/tagged/php). I want to search for questions where any or more of these tags exist. If I click on the saved favorite tag [php](/questions/tagged/php) and then [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), the PHP will be replaced, so I always have to select from the unanswered tags (where the selection is added not replaced).

So I'm always clicking the 3 tags which I have to find in the "unanswered tags" group. Is there any way I can search all my favorite tags at once?

Comment: This is both a dupe, and off-topic when specific to Stack Overflow alone (it isn't really).

Comment: All you have to do is search for `[jquery] [or] [ajax] [or] [php]` to get a tag page combining questions for any of those tags.

Comment: Sorry I miswrote, I meant "is containing any of". I have seen the [jquery][ajax][php] syntax, for the search field  however do I need to retype it everytime I want to search for these even tho I have them saved in favorite tags?

Comment: There is currently no way to convert your starred tags to such a search. I have my search simply bookmarked.

Comment: `intags:mine`. That's what you want.

Comment: I've confirmed that the suggestion by @Braiam works; voting to reopen.

Comment: Is there a way to limit it to just Questions =? Currently this give N+1 results for every question where N is the number of answers (1 per answer, + 1 for the Questions).

Comment: NVM: The solution I required is: 

**intags:mine is:question**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's actually an operator for this now: `intags:mine` (thanks @Braiam!). It isn't in the "Advanced Search Tips" displayed on the search page, but is documented [somewhere in the dark depths of the Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching), in section **User Operators**. Unlike the other user operators, it does not support querying arbitrary users' favourite tags; it will silently use yours instead.

Interestingly, the Help Center mention of the `intags:mine` operator has been around since early August 2013, more than a year ago ([documented on Aug 4](http://web.archive.org/web/20130804000825/https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching), but [not on Aug 2](http://web.archive.org/web/20130802070348/https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching)), but the Search Tips sidebar still doesn't mention it. This strikes me as a curious oversight.

Answer (score 0):

It's nice that there is a possibility to search for all my tags. I think for such a feature a button next to "favorite tags" would be great.

Comment: Or even better, a textbox: http://i.stack.imgur.com/6fS39.png (triggered by Enter, same way as the ordinary search on top)

Comment: @ShadowWizard hold on.. are you saying that already exists? I don't have that...

Comment: @Cai lol no, I added it myself locally, gave it as suggestion for the requested feature.

Comment: @ShadowWizard oh that makes more sense... ignore me :)